# can "topical issue" be used in this way?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I want to say that recently people are talking more about music and its effects on the community.

here is the sentence:

**"Fine arts, namely music, have been a topical issue latterly, in regard to their influence on the community"**

by "topical issue" I mean **"a trending topic"** or **"a topic of the day"**.

Comment: It could be used that way and probably understood, but "trending topic" would be a better choice.  (When I first saw "topical" I assumed you were talking about some sort of skin cream.)

Comment: latterly? when is that? But why not just say “in the news lately”?

Comment: Why "Fine arts, namely music" instead of just "Music has been (in the news lately)"?